# Prevent BrowserWindow hide on blur if user opens a dialog

Tags: electron

I'm building a tray app that should hide, if the user clicks on something outside the app. That's an easy task:

```
mainWindow.on("blur", () => {
  if (!mainWindow.webContents.isDevToolsOpened()) {
    mainWindow.hide();
  }
});
```

But what happens in my app is, that users can select files from there filesystem. If the dialog opens, the blur event from my mainWindow is emitted. What is the electron way of preventing this event when a dialog is opened?

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same problem on windows (not macOS).

Comment: Unfortunately not.